# Partition of real line by integer translates

Tags: general-topology

As mentioned in my last question ,  I was going through the following lecture note
introducing quotient topology .

homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~jsimon/COURSES/M132Fall07/M132Fall07_QuotientSpaces.pdf

On page 3 ,it mentions about the following partition of the real line
Let X be the real line R
1
. Let G be the additive group of integers,
Z. Define an action of G on R by n(x) = x + n for each n ∈ Z, x ∈ R. Here the set
Gx consists of all integer translates of the point x. Note that the sets Gx do form a
partition of X. That is, the relation x ∼ y ⇐⇒ there exists g ∈ G with g(x) = y is
an equivalence relation on X.

I am unable to get a clear picture of this partition of real line and how do these sets form an equivalence relation (being symmetric, transitive and reflexive ). Are these partitions into singletons ? How are the number of points equal the number of points in half open interval [0,1) ?

Comment: The elements of $Gx$ are of the form $\{x+n:n\in\mathbb Z\}$. For example, if $G\pi = \{\pi, \pi\pm 1, \pi\pm2, \ldots\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Two numbers are equivalent if and only if  they have the same *fractional part*. This is clearly an equivalence relation. Also each equivalence class has  a representative in the interval $[0,1)$, by definition of the fractional part.

Comment: @Bernhard : So , does it include as the sets of equivalence class ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand your question: what is `it`? Does it include `what` as the sets of equivalence classes?

Comment: @Bernhard : I meant does it include "singletons " as the sets of equivalence class ? Sorry for typing error .

Comment: The  partition is $\bigcup\limits_{x\in[0,1)}\{x+\mathbf Z\}=\mathbf R$. Each equivalence class $x+\mathbf Z$ is a discrete set. Does it answer your question?

Comment: @bernhard :yes..thank you